# flash client freezes when minimized

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

We are building a multiplayer flash game using actionscript 3.  The game is supposed to work in real-time.

We have an issue where if ou minimize the game client, it freezes- I can see this by previewing the minimized window, my character which is supposed to walk across the room has frozen.  This causes a real-time issue because anything happening while a players client is minimized will be missed...

Does anyone know why the flash client would stop/freeze when minimized, and if there is a way to prevent this?

Comment: Don't quote me but, I am pretty sure this is an innate function of the flash player where the UI will stop updating to free up the cpu.

Comment: So there is no way to prevent this?  I've just found out the same issue occurs in several other popular online games... It's too bad though, I'm not sure how we can work around this to make sure the game operates in real-time...

Comment: I don't know for sure. Maybe it stops updating the UI. And if you do all your computings on onEnterFrame then that will stopt. Maybe and I say maybe if you use a timer to do all the computions it might still work.

Comment: Sorry tested it,, also doesnt work.

Comment: are you using enterFrame event? If so change it to timer based. Chances are this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing is a couple of features added in version 10.1 to improve battery life and performance on mobile devices. See [this documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c36cfb8137124318eebc6-8000.html) for the full details. The main change to understand is that when a SWF is entirely offscreen (due to scrolling or tabbing), its frame rate is dropped to 2 fps. There's no way to disable this, AFAIK. (And I don't think there should be..)

For how to deal with it, many kinds of processing should work normally, as long as you don't make any implicit assumptions about framerate. The content will still get all the same events it would normally get (sockets and timers and so on), though it will process some of them less frequently than normal. So in general it's possible (and necessary) to make content that works in all cases as long as you are aware of how you expect timing to work and plan accordingly.

For example, if a character is walking across the screen, and the user minimizes the browser for a while, when the browser is maximized again should the character have reached his destination? In a single-player game maybe he shouldn't, but in a multiplayer game (where the character's location may be intended to represent server-side data) maybe he should. In the former case maybe it's best to use a frame animation that will slow down while minimized, but in the latter situation you almost certainly want a time-driven scripted tween - ideally you want the script that sets the character's location to know when he started walking, and when he is supposed to arrive, but not care how many times he is redrawn during the trip.

What you definitely *don't* want to do is run a Timer or an Interval that fires 30 times per second and update your content in that event. This just wastes a lot of CPU, since you're making lots of updates that will never be seen by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It will having this behaviour because Flash will stop visual computing in some specific situations while the player is not visible.
Probably you have a code which requires to compute textures, positions the whole time the application is running, and after you are trieing the restore the window - there is just too much to be computed, and it will took some time to get to the point which it is supposed to be if it were not minimized ( some linear code ).

Maybe the solution will be to stop computing the visual part while it is minimized.
Not quite sure but i think there is still not way to run in background mode yet with flash player.